# jquery empty text box event

Tags: jquery

I can make a div hide when a textbox is in use like this:

```
  $("#text-box").**keyup**(function(){
    $("#container").hide();
  });
```

....but how do I show the div again when the text box is empty:

```
 $("#text-box").**what-event-goes-here??**(function(){
    $("#container").show();
  });
```

Comment: When the `input`/`textarea` is *empty* but *still has focus,* or when it's empty and has *lost* focus?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: the correct event is 'keyup'

```
$("#text-box").bind("keyup", function() { 
   if ($(this).val() == "")
     $("#container").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if container is by default hidden then u can also use below code

```
$("#text-box").bind("keyup", function() { 
   if ($(this).val() =='')
     $("#container").show();
});
```